# How to write plugin CSS that override theme CSS

Tags: html, css

I wrote CSS for my plugin, but theme CSS overwriting that, I have tried and searched for this I did not get any solution

This is my HTML code

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <img src="sample.gif" width="100" height="132">
 <h1>This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text.</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

my CSS is

```
 img {
       float: right !important;
     }
```

And theme CSS is

```
  h1 {
       clear:both;
     }
```

I want my image to be displayed to the right side of h1 tag.

Comment: Plugin to what? CSS on tags instead of classes speaks to a bad theme definition to me.

Comment: what is the loading order of your css link and other link from theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the clear on the title... if that's not possible, override it

```css
img {
  float: right
}

h1 {
  clear: both !important
}

body h1 {
  clear: none !important
}
```

```html
<img src="sample.gif" width="100" height="132">
<h1>This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text. This is also some text.</h1>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @mayersdesign. it worked for me.